# "closest match" in SQL join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: Orders1 and Orders2, both with OrderDate column in them.  I want to join the two tables, matching the closest date in Order2 to Order1 -- the one single order in Order2 whose date is closest (greater than or equal to) the Order1 date.  I know I can do this with a correlated subquery.  But wouldn't a direct join (using a non equi operator) perform better?  I just can't figure out how to construct a direct join that returns only 1 row when using >=.

Minimal example:

```
 CREATE TABLE Order1(
  OrderDate DATE, 
  Info Varchar(256) );
CREATE TABLE Order2(
 OrderDate DATE,
 Info Varchar(256) );

Order1 Data:  
2022-09-01  'ABC'
2022-10-01  'XYZ'

Order2 Data:
2022-09-03  '123'
2022-09-04  '456'
2022-10-15  '000'
2022-10-17  '777'

Desired Output:
Order1.Orderdate, Order1.Info, Order2.Orderdate, Order2.Info
2022-09-01, 'ABC', 2022-09-03 '123'
2022-10-01, 'XYZ', 2022-10-15, '000'
```

Comment: This question is not clear. Post the tables you have and the desired result.

Comment: Please provide a clear problem description, DDL for your table descriptions (CREATE TABLE) for the tables, sample data (DML in the form of INSERT), and the output you want to obtain from that data, along with your efforts to solve the problem yourself. We cannot help without the relevant information.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for some kind of clustering, or finding the pairs in both tables that match best. The result would probably not be deterministic, and databases are not good at such things. You have to come up with a simple algorithm, something like "truncate both dates to the week and match rows that are equal after that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *lateral* join will do. [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bnTSVDHwKQDjdwrAKVXsw/0)

```sql
select o.OrderDate first_orderdate, o.Info first_info, 
       l.OrderDate second_orderdate, l.Info second_info
from Order1 as o left join lateral 
(
 select * 
 from Order2 
 where OrderDate >= o.OrderDate 
 order by OrderDate 
 limit 1
) as l on true;
```

| first_orderdate | first_info | second_orderdate | second_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | ABC | 2022-09-03 | 123 |
| 2022-10-01 | XYZ | 2022-10-15 | 000 |